# the json data is repeated every time it performs input and the input entered does not appear on the display

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, redux-toolkit

I'm just learning next js. i am trying to make a simple todo list using json todos api as the data. in making the program I used the redux toolkit as a fetching todos data. but when I create new data or add new data, the added data does not appear on the display and every word that is entered into the input instead occurs a todos data loop which I fetch. Please help me resolve the error.

todoApi.js

```
`import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

// fetching api
export const todosApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'}),
    tagTypes: ['Todos'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        todos: builder.query({
            query: () => '/todos',            
        }),
        todosStart: builder.query({
            query: (page = 0) => `/todos?_start=${page}&_limit=10`,
            providesTags: ['Todos']
        }),
        addTodos: builder.mutation({
            query: (todo) => ({
                url: '/todos',
                method: 'POST',
                body: todo,
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Todos']
        }),
        updateTodos: builder.mutation({
            query: (todo) => ({
                url: `/todos/${todo.id}`,
                method: 'PATCH',
                body: todo
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Todos']
        }),
        deleteTodos: builder.mutation({
            query: ({id}) => ({
                url: `/todos/${id}`,
                method: 'DELETE',
                body: id
            })
        })
    })
})

export const { 
    useTodosStartQuery,
    useTodosQuery,
    useAddTodosMutation, 
    useUpdateTodosMutation,
    useDeleteTodosMutation
} = todosApi`
```

and this simple todo app

todosList.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faUpload, faTrash } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { useTodosQuery, useAddTodosMutation, useUpdateTodosMutation, useDeleteTodosMutation, useTodosStartQuery } from './api/todosApi' 


function TodoList() {

    
    // status kosong
    const [addItemTodos, setAddItemTodos] = useState('')

    const {
        data: todos = [],
        error,
        isLoading,
        isSuccess
    } = useTodosStartQuery()
    
    const [addTodos] = useAddTodosMutation()
    const [updateTodos] = useUpdateTodosMutation()
    const [deleteTodos] = useDeleteTodosMutation()

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        addTodos()
    }

    console.log(todos.map(todo => todo))

    
    const newItemSection = (
        <form >
            <label>Add Todo Item</label>
            <div>
                <input type='text' value={addItemTodos} onChange={(e) => setAddItemTodos(e.target.value)}/>                                    
            </div>
            <button className='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>Upload</button>
        </form>
    )

    let contentTodoList

    if(isLoading){
        contentTodoList =  <h2>Data Json being Loading</h2>
    }else if(error){
        contentTodoList = <h2>Something Wrong</h2>
    }else if(isSuccess){
        contentTodoList = todos.map(todo => {
            return (
                <article key={todo.id}>
                    <div className='todo-item'>
                        <input type='checkbox' checked={todo.completed} id={todo.id} onChange={() => updateTodos({...todo, completed: !todo.completed})}/>
                        <label htmlFor={todo.id}>{todo.title}</label>
                        <button onClick={() => deleteTodos({id: todo.id})}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </article>
            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>React List</h1>
            {newItemSection}
            {contentTodoList}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoList
```

and this provider for api

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
// import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ApiProvider } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react'
// import { store } from './api/store'
import { todosApi } from './api/todosApi'
import TodoList from './TodoList'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <ApiProvider api={todosApi}>
          <TodoList/>
        </ApiProvider>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

[that a simple todo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik0fI.png)

Answer (score 0):

On every char input, you're setting the component state.

`<input type='text' value={addItemTodos} onChange={(e) => setAddItemTodos(e.target.value)}/>`

This rerenders the component and you make a new call every time.
Whatever you want to achieve can be done on the `onSubmit` handler.

Comment: I've tried using onSubmit on the form element in the newItemSection variable, but the result is that the input that is entered cannot be displayed

Comment: @HoviSohibulWafa By input do you mean every character, or you mean it text is not added to todos?

Comment: every character. every character that is entered into the input element instead occurs repetition of the called json data